# C++ Multi Dimensional Array Problems - Entries printed more than once

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a 15x20 array, and I want to change the value of each entry, then cout them all.

```
char map[15][80];
```

Here is my code to cout all entries.

```
for (int a=0;a<=15;a++) {
              for (int b=0;b<=80;b++) {
                  map[a][b] = 'a';
                  cout << map[a][b]; } }
```

The problem occurs if I place the alphabet into an array, it will print a certain letter more than once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char map[15][80];
```

Your for loops are reading one element past the array you allocated.

```
for (int a=0;a<=15;a++) 
             ^^^^^

for (int b=0;b<=80;b++)
             ^^^^^
```

Valid indexes are only from `0` to `14` in first case &
`0` to `79` in second case.

Note that C/C++ do not do array bounds checking for you, So you have to be careful about not writing beyond the bounds of the array, if you do so what you get is **Undefined Behavior**, which means your C/C++ program is not valid anymore.

Comment: Oh geez, that's barely noticeable. Good catch.